# How to reference the home directory in .user.ini

Tags: php, logging, ini

I'd like to log PHP errors into a custom file. Therefore I set the `error_log` directive. Using the absolute path to the users home-directory works fine:

```
error_log = /customers/homepages/245/28134556/htdocs/My_Logs/php.log
```

I'd prefer to use a relative path, but I couldn't figure out how to correctly reference the home directory (which is `/customers/homepages/245/28134556/htdocs`). I tried:

```
error_log = ~/My_Logs/php.log
error_log = "${HOME}/My_Logs/php.log"
```

On http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#example-6172 I read the ENV-variables are available in .ini-files,... and at least my my login-shell the are. So I don't understand why the second example is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there's an 'E' in the variables_order setting in php.ini (http://php.net/variables-order), otherwise ENV variables are not set.